# Paypal not accepting the FORM in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, paypal

I am integrating paypal gateway in my angularjs app. In that I am submitting form with various input field. In that form, I am setting up value of amount dynamically 
For example:   `<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="{{paypal_data.reward_amount}}">`

But paypal is not accepting form and displaying following error.

> The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an
>   incorrectly formatted item amount.

The value is setting to amount successfully. When I use input type= "text" instead of  "hidden" then its displaying correct value in textbox but paypal is not accepting form. How to set value dynamically to input with another method so that the form will accept by paypal.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem but paypal accepts only 2 decimal places for the amount, check if `paypal_data.reward_amount` only has 2 places after the decimal

Comment: thanks @DTing... I've checked but its not working

Comment: hmmm ... why don't you use `ng-model`?

Comment: I've used that too...but no luck

Comment: And do you use angular to post it? Or do you call `form.submit()`. Because if you use angular, then it should work correctly. The `value="{{}}"` is kinda weird ...

Comment: Got it. I am using `form.submit()`....but how do I post it using angular? Because I am submitting the form automatically.

Comment: I got another thing that is I am submitting form automatically using jquery that's why its happening. If I submit the form by clicking on 'buy' button then its working fine. But I want to submit this form automatically. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe different method is called when clicking `buy` button and when calling `form.submit()`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91483/discussion-between-omkar-and-david-votrubec).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've fixed this by applying some logic. I used below JQuery code 
 `setTimeout(function(){},100);`  
I've submitted the form by applying some delay using function. 
I think when I using only `$("#paybtn").click(); //Automatic Button Click function` it was submitting form before assigning value to input.  Finally I used below code that worked successfully to me

```
setTimeout(function(){ $("#paybtn").click(); },0);
```